# Can light travel through a maze?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, absorption

I want to manufacture a light proof enclosure. I need to understand: if I design a cap with a "U" section profile edge and the body with "T" or "U" section profile edge, will light be able to get inside or is this solution insufficient?

Update: I'm attaching the following image that is defining my problem.[image]

Comment: Related. This uses mirrors. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161767/37364

Answer (score 3):

If you paint the inside surfaces flat black, or cover them with black felt, a "maze" will let air through but stop 99.9% of the light.

Comment: I've updated my question with an image. Basically I have same solution on film bulk loader. It has gaps as there are movable parts but has this kind of traps.

Answer (score 0):

yes light can travel through a maze and of course the more intricate the maze the less light will escape.

As @S. McGrew mentionned, there are several techniques used to stop light, you can find these techs discussed on telecope forums. I'll add the the sand paper painted black.

Comment: I've updated my question with an image